# ToDataSet() replacement ArcGISI 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, c#

I am currently upgrading 9.3 codes to 10.1. There used to be ToDataSet() function in ESRI.ArcGIS.Utility.Converter class. Class still exists in ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF, but ToDataSet function is gone. Does anyone knows if there was a replacement provided, or there is an easy way to convert geodatabases IRecordSet to System.Data.DataSet?

Comment: Wrote my own function. So still hope for a useful standart solution.

Comment: There's a solution [on this archived forums post](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1707&t=209915) that would likely work for anyone else revisiting this. Note the `ESRI.ArcGIS.Utility.Converter` class was deprecated a very long time ago, which is probably why the helper functions aren't showing up.